# What is the recommend way to get the main Activity from child Activity

Tags: android

My android application has 1 main activity. And it launches some sub-activity (which I wrote) and that also launches some sub-activity (which I wrote).  I do this:

```
 Intent i = new Intent("my intent1");
 startActivity(i);
```

My question is how can each of my sub-activity and sub-sub-activity get back to the Parent activity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You should start your sub Activities via [startActivityForResult()][1], and when you're done in your sub-activity, call `finish()`.  This will close the sub-activity and return to the Activity that called startActivityForResult.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: Basically, I want to start a Toast in my subActivity or subsubActivity, but it can stay there even if user back from my subActivity/sbusubActivity (until he/she back all the way from the MainActivity).  Can I do that?

Comment: The Toast will remain up for the specified duration, even if you back all the way out to the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a method getParent() which returns the parent Activity of a child activity.

Comment: That only works if the Activity is embedded in another Activity.  Like an Activity that is the content of one of the tabs in a TabActivity; getParent() will return the TabActivity;

Comment: If, inside an activity (say listactivity), there are some UI logic in and adapter, which want to close/access its calling activity. How can an adapter refer to its activity and send some parameter too? (not only notifyDataChange().)